# Android Studio Emulator doesn't open

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Why android studio doesn't open emulator when I execute the program first time.

I use Android studio for the first time.

[Here is the image of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7Lg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeLXF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `C:\Users\ user \.android\.avd\` directory and delete all files in there. After that restart your Android studio and create new virtual device and it should work then.

Comment: I try that , but throw same error

Answer (score 0):

Do below steps

**1, First delete all you created virtual devices**

**2, Clean Project** Build => Clean Project

**3, Invalidate cache and Restart**

**4, Sync Project with gradle files.** Files => Sync Project with gradle files

5, Check SDK **" Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver "** installed. Only **Intel Processor**

**5, Re-install virtual device**

Answer (score -1):

**main cause this type of error happens by Low system storage.**

if your system low storage. please **clean up..** and try again.. it will work

Comment: I have enough storage.